# How to create a user in django with custom attributes using create_user?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, middleware

I'm trying to run a test of the middleware of a django app. Looks like this:

```
    class TestAuthenticationMiddleware(TestCase):
        @classmethod
        def setUpTestData(cls):
            cls.user = User.objects.create_user('test_user', 'test@example.com', 'test_password')

        def setUp(self):
            self.middleware = AuthenticationMiddleware(lambda req: HttpResponse())
            self.client.force_login(self.user)
            self.request = HttpRequest()
            self.request.session = self.client.session
```

But I'm getting this attribute error:

```
    queryset = user.get_subscriptions_all()
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'get_subscriptions_all'
```

because the User class is defined like this:

```
User(AbstractBaseUser, LimitHelpers):
    [...]
    def get_subscriptions_all(self):
        return self.subscriptions.all().union(self.account.subscriptions.all())
```

and on my utils.py:

```
        @receiver(user_logged_in)
    def callback_user_loggedin(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
        if not user.is_staff and not user.is_superuser:
            # Activating user's language
            saveCodeCountryFromUser(request, user)
            # Updating subscriptions
            queryset = user.get_subscriptions_all()
            for sub in queryset:
                cls = get_subscription_class(sub)
                if cls is not None:
                    cls.callback_user_loggedin()
```

Any idea about how to use the create_user to include the get_subscriptions_all attr?

Comment: Exactly where does this `queryset = user.get_subscriptions_all` originates from? Did you set the `User` as the `AUTH_USER_MODEL`?

Comment: I just added it... I'm using a custom user, without the AUTH_USER_MODEL.

Comment: Then the `callback_useer_loggedin` function is called with the Django `User` model, so `user` is not *your* custom `User` model object, but the "builtin" `User` model object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the setting `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.models.User'`

See: [substituting a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Without this setting, Django will continue to use the default builtin `User`. You should also ensure your tests also have this configuration (if you use a separate config for tests)